# Dependency Injection in ViewModelBase - Best practice

Tags: c#, design-patterns, inversion-of-control

I am using a `LoggerService` in my `ViewModelBase`, which is injected in constructor:

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ILoggerService _loggerService;

    public ViewModelBase(ILoggerService loggerService)
    {
       _loggerService = loggerService;
    }

    ...
    ...

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

But in my `ViewModelOne`, which inherits from `ViewModelBase`, I need to use this service, what should I do?

- To do public the `_loggerService` in `ViewModelBase` and use it from `ViewModelOne`.
- To inject again the interface in the constructor of `ViewModelOne`.

In your opinion, which would be the best approach? Or...what would you do?

Comment: you could make _loggerService protected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your ILoggerService protected and readonly so that only base class can assign value on it.

```
protected readonly ILoggerService _loggerService;
```

Refrain from doing it public so that you only know one place to check it and only one class has responsible on it, which is your base class.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to inject `ILoggerService` twice. Change the `_loggerService` from `private` to `protected` as following:

```
private ILoggerService _loggerService;
```

Or declare a `getLoggerService` in the supper class and then call it to get the logger instance in subclass:

```
protected ILoggerService getLoggerService() {
  return _loggerService;
}
```

Note that it makes no sense for other classes to get logger service from `ViewModelBase`, so it's better to declare `getLoggerService` as `protected`.